# physics of the 1-dimensional wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

I was given the task to solve the 1-dimensional wave equation
$$
\partial_{tt}u-\partial_{xx}u=0
$$
with the conditions
\begin{align}
 u(x,0)&=f(x), \\
 \partial_tu(x,0)&=0,
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{supp}f\subseteq[-1,1]$.

By factorizing the equation into
$$
(\partial_t-\partial_x)(\partial_t+\partial_x)u=0
$$
and using new variables, and then applying the initial conditions, I get the general solution
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+t)+f(x-t)).
$$

Now I'm asked to interpret the solution the following way: If I'm sitting on the real line at point $x=10$, at what time will I be able to see the wave for the first time and how long am I able to observe it?

My guess would be that I don't see the wave at all, since $f\equiv0$ outside of $[-1,1]$ but maybe I'm misinterpreting that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave is observable when at least one of $x\pm t$ is in $f$'s support, i.e. from $t=-11$ to $t=-9$, then again from $t=9$ to $t=11$.

Comment: ooh, so considering positive time the wave is observable in the time interval $[9,11]$